# Best practice to set VertxOptions in a class that extends AbstractVerticle

Tags: java, microservices, vert.x, vertxoptions, abstractverticle

I'm learning by a [mission-http-api-vertx](https://appdev.openshift.io/docs/vertx-runtime.html#mission-http-api-vertx) 
coding my customizations on the scaffold generated by **developers.redhat.com/launch** using **Eclipse Vert.x 3.4.2**  .

I think the proposed approach is quite a *classic*  but I do not understand what is the best practice  to set `VertxOptions` in `public class HttpApplication extends AbstractVerticle {`

What I'm trying:

```java
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;

public class HttpApplication extends AbstractVerticle {
  protected final int DEFAULT_ADDRESS_RESOLUTION_TIMEOUT = 8000;
  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> future) {
    //  [snip] Create a router object and routes
    // my custom options code start-here:[
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions()
                .setWarningExceptionTime(1500000000)
                .setAddressResolverOptions(new AddressResolverOptions()
                        .addServer("192.168.0.1")
                        .addServer("192.168.2.1")
                        .setMaxQueries(5)
                        .setCacheNegativeTimeToLive(0) // discard failed DNS lookup results immediately
                        .setCacheMaxTimeToLive(0) // support DNS based service resolution
                        .setRotateServers(true)
                        .setQueryTimeout(DEFAULT_ADDRESS_RESOLUTION_TIMEOUT));

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);
    // my custom options code:  end-here:]

    // Create the HTTP server and pass the "accept" method to the request handler.
    vertx
        .createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(router::accept)
        .listen(
```

in particular I am very doubtful whether it is correct or not to get a vertx in `Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);` while the gerated code simply uses the *Reference to the Vert.x instance that deployed this verticle* provided by the abstract base class `AbstractVerticle`.

It's my approach safe?  has it contraindications or risks breaking something? Is there a better practice to setup my custom `VertxOptions` in `HttpApplication`?

Comment: This is not correct, since you create another instance of VertX inside your verticle. How do you start VertX in the first place?

Comment: You should use Vert.x instance provided as [field](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/rxjava/core/AbstractVerticle.html#vertx) of ```AbstractVerticle```.

Comment: @Nonequen by the Vert.x instance provided as field of AbstractVertiche is it possible to .setAddressResolverOptions adding a couple of server like I did in my question code sample ?

Comment: @Alexey I agree with you that it's not correct: I also asked to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vertx  and , so far , the best option for me,  is to implement my own `Launcher`  that `extends VertxCommandLauncher implements VertxLifecycleHooks`. I launch my VertX as a fatjar  and in the scaffold generated by scaffold generated by developers.redhat.com/launch basically there is only a public class HttpApplication extends AbstractVerticle